# Visual Studio's Test Runner with Chutzpah won't recognize QUnit tests when using both Requirejs and knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2013, requirejs, qunit, chutzpah

I'm trying to get VS 2013 test explorer with Chutzpah to recognize QUnit tests while I'm using require.js in combination with knockoutjs

I've found some good resources listed below but I think I must just have one missing piece.

- [This is what I used](http://www.nathandavison.com/article/17/using-qunit-and-requirejs-to-build-modular-unit-tests) to ensure I was using Qunit and require.js together correctly.
- [From this resource](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=requirejs), it sounds like I need a Chutzpah.json file as well.

Here is what I can reproduce:

- If I just use Chutzpah and qunit I can get it to work so I know I have Chutzpah installed correctly for VS test runner.

**example: testThatWorks.js**

```
        test("test that shows up in test explorer", function () {
            equal("444test", "444test");
        });
```

- If view index.html in a browser it runs my tests with the correct results.
- If I use the define syntax it also works

**example: testThatAlsoWorks.js**

```
define(
function () {

    test("Test that also shows up in test explorer.", function () {
        equal("444test", "444test");
    });

});
```

- If I use the require syntax for including any other resource it fails (this loads knockout but doesn't actually use it)

**example: testThatDoesn'tWork.js**

```
define(['knockout'],
function (ko) {

    test("Test that doesn't show up in test explorer.", function () {
        equal("444test", "444test");
    });
});
```

This is what VS 2013 Test explorer shows:

[image]

Here is the relevant project setup (there are other files for my real project but I'm trying to keep it simple here):

```
index.html (think I won't need this once I get it working in VS test runner)
tests
   references
      qunit.css
      qunit.js
      qunit.html
   chutzpah.json
   unittestsmain.js (think I won't need this once I get it working in VS test runner)
   testThatWorks.js
   testThatDoesntWork.js
   testThatAlsoWorks.js
Scripts
   jquery stuff
   require.js stuff
   knockout stuff
   ...
```

Here is my chutzpah.json

```
{
   "Framework": "qunit",
   "TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
   "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
   "References" : [
      {"Path" : "../Scripts/require.js" }
   ]
}
```

This is the timeout error in the Chutzpah.log file

> Error: Error: Timeout occured when executing test file
>   While Running:c:\workingfoldertfs\lesa-it\developers\whitezelb\chutzpahexample\chutzpahexample\chutzpahexample\tests\testthatdoesntwork.js
>   vstest.executionengine.x86.exe Error: 0 : Time:12:45:01.2839495; Thread:34; Message:Headless browser returned with an error: Timeout occured when executing test file

Comment: I am confused as to what it not working? Also, can you upload a full repro to github so I can test locally?

Comment: @MatthewManela I've updated the question with some progress I've made and I think it is isolating the real problem I'm having. I will also upload to github in a couple minutes.

Comment: @MatthewManela full example solution published at https://github.com/BethWhitezel/Chutzpah-VS2013andRequireJS-example

Comment: Maybe it is related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/22124292/451736

Comment: @MatthewManela is it correct that the order of the References in the Chutzpah.json file matter? See my answer below... it seems to matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was caused by not using the correct "paths" for the dependencies. The example I show above works if the testthatdoesntwork.js file is changed to:

```
define(['../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0'],
function (knockout) {
    test("Test that doesn't show up in test explorer.", function () {
        equal("444test", "444test");
    }); 
});
```

and the Chutzpah.json file looks like:

```
{
"Framework": "qunit",
"TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
"TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
"References" : [
     {"Path" : "../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js" },
     {"Path" : "../Scripts/require.js" }

]
}
```

Looking at https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/workitem/214 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22124292/451736 helped me figure out the problem I was having.

It also appears that the order of the References in the Chutzpah.json file matter because with everything else the same and the json file changed to the below the test doesn't show.

```
{
"Framework": "qunit",
"TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
"TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
"References" : [
     {"Path" : "../Scripts/require.js"} ,
     {"Path" : "../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"}

]
}
```

Comment: Correct, the order in the references section is very important

Comment: Thanks... you've been VERY helpful. Is there documentation that I missed that talks about what the order should be? I'm actually trying to get it to work with knockout and knockout.mapping but can't figure out if it is the order I have wrong or the reference or both.

Comment: Well, basically Chutzpah will put those in the same order in the HTML file it generates. So you need to figure out for your references how you would make it work if you were just building a HTML file manually to run your tests. Then tell Chutzpah to do the same

Comment: That makes sense but require.js and knockout don't have dependencies on each other so I'm still a little confused about why the order matters between the two of those. I'm guessing that my lack of understanding there is what is preventing me from understanding the problem I'm having getting knockout.mapping to load. Is the HTML file that Chutzpah generates available somewhere I can view? That may help me understand

Comment: I think Knockout defines its own require function that can mess with the Require.js one if the order is wrong.

Comment: @MatthewManela thank you so much for the help. That helped me get it working with knockout.mapping as well. I found that I could see the HTML if it was while it was waiting for the timeout to happen and that allowed me to better see the real errors. All is working great now.